# Communicate to Virtual Machine

Tags: rest, vmware

I want to connect with virtual machine on another computer from my computer.I am trying to do it using Advance Rest client.How do I set up the network? IP of Virtual machine is private IP(192.168.195.132).So the communication is not happening.What to do?
Thanks

Comment: what is your host OS ? and guest (VM) OS ? what kind of virtualization software you are using like VMWare ??

Comment: HOST OS:Windows 7 Virtual OS:Ubuntu 12.04...Vmware Workstation

Answer (score 0):

This has to do with Virtual Machine network configuration (assuming its vmware from your question tags)

[Does this help](http://www.vmware.com/support/ws55/doc/ws_net_configurations_custom.html) ?

Comment: [How to assign public ip to my guest](http://communities.vmware.com/thread/197195)